# Error while executing query

Tags: django

I get an error message on this query

```
query = "select count(*) from pgns_game where raw_moves = %s"
params = ('a',)
total_rows = self.model.objects.raw(query, params)
```

and it says

```
InvalidQuery('Raw query must include the primary key')
```

I am clearly missing something but I don't know what. Any ideas?

Comment: Says here in the docs ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/sql/#deferring-model-fields ):  "There is only one field that you can't leave out—the primary key field. Django uses the primary key to identify model instances, so it must always be included in a raw query. An InvalidQuery exception will be raised if you forget to include the primary key."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`self.model.objects.raw()` expects the query result to contain primary keys from the model `self.model`, so it can turn these into a list of objects for the function result.

What you really need to do is [execute the SQL directly, and not through a manager.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)  Your code will probably look like this:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select count(*) from pgns_game where raw_moves = %s", ['a'])
total_rows = cursor.fetchone()
```

I haven't tried this myself, though.